# What are the best practices to enable CORS for docker containerized ASP.NET core app

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What are the best practices to enable CORS in asp.net core api, which is containerized to docker container? Docker compose is used.

For asp.net core API cors is enabled in Startup.cs. In Debug mode there are no issues with CORS. But when I put this application into Docker container, CORS headers are missing.

I have read about Nginx, but it`s not the best approach for me.

I have Angular 6 on the frontend. On the backend I have ASP.NET Core API.
Basically when I run asp.net core application in debug mode, it can be invoked from local front-end. When I added and run my backend in Docker container I am not able to invoke it from Front-end.

Error I have:
- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "best practice". There is only "something that works well enough for you". Can you better describe the issue you're facing and what you've done to try and address it so far?

Comment: You basically have 2 options; offload CORS to something in your infrastructure (reverse proxy, API management solution, etc.) or handle it yourself in your .NET Core app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0. Without knowing what you're trying to do it's hard to tell which is best for you.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I've ran into a similar issue with Firefox.  Turns out it was an issue with certificate (self-signed without CA certificate), but for some reason pipeline kept saying it's CORS.  When I tried Chrome or Edge I was able to bypass the warning.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not specific for asp.net, but more general.

There's nothing special about CORS when using docker or docker-compose. But, from a networking perspective, when using multiple docker containers you are closer to the end setup with multiple components interacting via network, and CORS configurations will probably be needed.

So, I'd say best-practice will depend on the use case. Are you using docker and docker-compose for testing purposes? If so, I'd just define specific configurations for your docker setup for an equivalent setup as debug mode, e.g. using ENV vars.